# Dimension and intersection of algebraic varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $L,M$ be projective varieties over $\mathbb C$ of same dimension.

1) Assuming $L$ and $M$ are embedded hypersurfaces in $\mathbb{P}^n$, is it true that $L$ and $M$ must have non-empty intersection? If $n=2$ yes, this is Bézout's theorem, but wikipedia states something for the intersection of $n$ hypersurfaces in $\mathbb{P}^n$...

2) Is it true that either $L=M$ or $L \cap M$ has dimension strictly less than that of $L$ and $M$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Yes. As you mention, this follows from the general version of Bezout's theorem. But there is a more basic explanation, as follows:

> **Proposition:** Let $L$ and $M$ be subvarieties of $\mathbf P^n$ with $\operatorname{dim} L = n-1$ and $\operatorname{dim }M >0$. Then $L \cap M \neq \emptyset$.

*Proof:* Using the appropriate Veronese embedding,  we see that $\mathbf P^n \setminus L$ is affine. But an affine variety cannot contain a projective subvariety of positive dimension.

2) The answer depends on your definition of "variety".

If it includes "irreducible", then the answer is yes: a proper closed subset of an irreducible variety has lower dimension than the variety. (This is either an exercise or completely immediate, depending on your definition of dimension.)

If "variety" does not include "irreducible", then the answer is no: $L \cap M$ could be a common maximal-dimensional component of $L$ and $M$.